# Dependency manager for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd

Are there any JavaScript dependency managers that would not rely on loading modules async/ fetching data from server? I know require.js and others but it seems that it's not what I'm looking for or maybe I misunderstood them.

I have Backbone classes defined in one file and some other stuff in another and I use squishit to combine all JavaScript files into one(avoid multiple requests). Everything works fine, but I see that there maybe some issues in the future with dependency handling.
Now I have a choice and I can use one of many AMD loaders(such as require) and my problem would be solved but then again, I'm using squishit so I can avoid multiple requests to server and by using AMD loader I couldn't do that. I saw that I could use require-optimizer to combine some modules into packages if I were using Java or Node - which I don't.

So I tried to look for something that did only dependency management without async loading and failed to find anything.

Does anyone know anything that would do what I want? Thank you

Comment: I have used, requireJS and its optimizer. You need node only when you are minifying everything. So why not use require-optimizer with node?

Comment: @janith Because I'm using .net not Node :)

Comment: So does it matter, i mean you can do all your code and the back end, and run them un-minified, and when deploying you run the optimizer with node installed. Or is it that you want some kind of a continuous integration set up?

Comment: What I want is simple dependency manager which would not make any calls to the backend. For example I give list of .js files:
BB.models.js;
BB.collections.js;
BB.views.js;
jQuery.js;
Backbone.js; etc.. etc..
After I combine them all in one big file I want to have no problems when one or another file is not loaded yet. What require.js offers is to define dependecnys and load it async from server, but since I already have all files loaded I only need to manage dependencies so that files are executed in the right order.

Comment: ok...Im not sure if i understood properly, but here goes, Requirejs optemizer takes your scripts and puts it into a single file, and also preserves your depenancies so you will not have any problems of scripts not loading.

Comment: Ok, so it seems that I misunderstood it: "The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays of string literals that are passed to top-level require and define calls" - what I understand from this is that it will make packages, rather than one big file? Or is it able to put everything into one file?

Comment: It will take all the dependencies minify them and inject into the main file.

Comment: With the requireJS optimizer, after optimization the original files will be also copied into the optimized directory, however since all the dependencies have been included in the main file by loading that file alone you can run your application.

Comment: Thank you for replies, I will try to do it. It seems that I will need to setup Node on CI server to optimize scripts, rather than use Squishit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one suggested Require.js + optimizer on a separate anwser I'm gonna answer my own question.

After searching and reading a lot I found that Require.js + node would fit best for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked that closely, but Google Closure's dependency management seems VERY configurable. You may be able to build everything at 'compile' time the way you want it.

http://blog.carduner.net/2009/11/08/using-google-closure-with-your-js-libraries/